# Group using two columns and mark rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to mark rows depending on other two columns. I must group and next mark.

I have the next dataframe:

[image]

And I must do next:

[image]]

The column_4 is done, I did next:

`df['column_4'] = df.groupby(['column_1',"column_2"]).cumcount() + 1`

But I can't with column_3. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift` + `ne` to create a mask, and then `groupby` + `cumsum` to turn it into numbers for your 3rd column:

```
df['column 4'] = df.groupby(['column 1', 'column 2']).cumcount().add(1)
df['column 3'] = df['column 2'].ne(df['column 2'].shift()).groupby(df['column 1']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   column 1 column 2  column 3  column 4
0         A        x         1         1
1         A        x         1         2
2         A        x         1         3
3         A        y         2         1
4         A        y         2         2
5         A        z         3         1
6         B        p         1         1
7         B        p         1         2
8         B        p         1         3
9         C        i         1         1
10        C        o         2         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert each group's col2 values to categorical and get the category codes.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'],
                  'column_2':['x','x','x','y','y','z','p','p','p','i','o']})

df['column_3'] = df.groupby('column_1')['column_2'].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes+1)
df['column_4'] = df.groupby(['column_1',"column_2"]).cumcount() + 1

print(df)
```

Output

```
   column_1 column_2  column_3  column_4
0         A        x         1         1
1         A        x         1         2
2         A        x         1         3
3         A        y         2         1
4         A        y         2         2
5         A        z         3         1
6         B        p         1         1
7         B        p         1         2
8         B        p         1         3
9         C        i         1         1
10        C        o         2         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try group by `column 1` and then group by `column 2` in subgroup and use `ngroup()` to get group id.

```py
df['column 3'] = df.groupby('column 1').apply(lambda group: group.groupby('column 2').ngroup()+1).droplevel(level=0)
```

```
print(df)

   column 1 column 2  column 3
0         A        x         1
1         A        x         1
2         A        x         1
3         A        y         2
4         A        y         2
5         A        z         3
6         B        p         1
7         B        p         1
8         B        p         1
9         C        i         1
10        C        o         2
```